# To check if values are updated in MySQl after update trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am converting a trigger from MSSQL to MySQL. There I came across a statement

```
IF NOT UPDATE(UpdatedDateTime)
```

How to check for the same condition in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can compare the `NEW` and `OLD` values. MySQL provides a null-safe equality comparator, which returns true or false. (A NULL value is considered to be "equal to" another NULL value, and "unequal to" a non-NULL value)

```
IF NOT ( NEW.updateddatetime <=> OLD.updateddatetime )
```

NOTE: I'm not sure of the behavior of the Transact-SQL `UPDATE(foo)`, and whether what I posted above is equivalent or not. What I posted above is how you would detect whether a different value was assigned to a column; the example I gave does *not* detect whether a value was *supplied* for a column as part of the `SET` clause in an UPDATE statement.